# Magento2 how to getRequest

Tags: magento2, http-request

In Magento 2 how to receive request array? `$_POST` and `$_GET` too as we did in Magento 1:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost()
```

Comment: Can you specify in which class you want POST and GET data.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you are trying this from a controller that extends `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` you can get the request with `$this->getRequest()->getPost()`.
If you are in a custom class, you need to inject the request in the constructor.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Something;
class ClassName 
{
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
        ....//rest of parameters here
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
       ...//rest of constructor here
    }
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->request->getPostValue();//in Magento 2.*
    }
}
```

Comment: what about $_GET ?

Comment: Same way. Just use getParams instead of getPost

Comment: Thx, it works. I tried in PHPstorm with xDebug and look in window Watches. But I got empty array.

Comment: My class `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` does not have a method `getPost`, are you sure about this?

Comment: @peedee: It's extended from \Zend\Http\Request

Comment: When you do this, `vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=MEQP2` throws:
`19 | WARNING | Request\Http object MUST NOT be requested in constructor. It can only be passed as a method argument.`

Comment: @JeroenVermeulen-MageHost there was no MEQP2 standard 2.5 years ago when I wrote this.

Comment: I got empty array. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/229614/55981

Comment: @nagendra use `getValuePost`. I updated the answer

Comment: its getPostValue. I updated answer

Answer (score 24):

Hi you can get it easily in models, blocks and controllers by using:

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost()
```

Or add `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` to the constructor parameters in your own classes:

```
<?php
namespace MyModuleNameSpace\MyModule\Block
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class MyClass
{
    /**
     * Request instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getMyPostParams()
    {
        $postData = $this->request->getPost();
    }
}
```

Comment: My `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` does not have a method `getPost()`, are you sure about this?

Comment: Did you try the code? Calling `$this->getRequest()->getPost();` returns an `Zend\Stdlib\Parameters` object for me. Even in core, Magento uses plenty calls like this, with a parameter like for example in `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddComment` there is on line 31 a call: `$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('history');`

Comment: @AmitBera I need help, Is there a way to call `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\ReadHandler` plugin class to only in get product details API ?

Answer (score 3):

This should work, just test it.
Compare and see what is missing.

```
<?php
namespace MyModuleNameSpace\MyModule\Block
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class MyClass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Request instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getMyPostParams()
    {
        $postData = $this->request->getPost();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the template, we don't need to re-declare the request variable. We have already : `$this->_request`

Answer (score 1):

```
private $params = ['id', 'name'];

public function execute()
{
    $this->getPostParams();
}

private function getPostParams()
{
    foreach ($this->params as $k) 
    {
        $this->params[$k] = $this->getRequest->getParam($k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use data persister(\Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistor) to get URL param in controller using Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http, than save and use it in collection class(where Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http is not working), take guidance from this [How to pass data to UiComponent Area](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139159/how-to-pass-data-to-uicomponent-area)

```
$this->dataPersistor->set($key, $data)//in your controller

$this->dataPersistor->get($key)// in your collection

$this->dataPersistor->clear($key)in your collection once value used.
```

Answer (score -1):

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\ControllerName;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class ActionName extends Action

{

```
public function __construct(

    Action\Context $context,

) {

    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()

{

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).