# How to pass data to UiComponent Area

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, registry

I have try to use register to save value and call it in some place of UiComponent such as ButtonProvider or Field OptionSource but seem it doesn't work. Is that a right way to do it or i am doing wrong

In controller i save variable to register

```
$this->_coreRegistry->register('someVal',data);
```

In another place i get data by registry

```
$this->_coreRegistry->registry('someVal');
```

Answer (score 3):

I found solution for my question. Use Persistor instead of registry. Some case you need to pass data to Component area such as : Form. You can use Persistor to get this data instead use registry. Registry usually use in Controllers or Models

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

/**
 * @var DataPersistorInterface
 */
protected $dataPersistor;

public function __construct(
    DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
){
    $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
}

protected function saveDataToPersistor() {
 $this->dataPersistor->set('val', $value);
}
```

To get data in persistor use `get` method

```
$this->dataPersistor->get('val');
```

Comment: Any chance you could show how you retrieved the information in you ui-component xml ?

Comment: Dataprovider define in xml form responsible to retrieve and populate data.