# Magento 2 get Parameters in the URL

Tags: magento2, collection, filter, uicomponent

I have created an admin form with phtml content and a ui component grid. Phtml section working fine. Now I want to filter the grid collection based on the url param. I have used the below code
`$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')` to recieve the url param,but it gives error. Here is my grid collection code.

```
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Collection as CustomCollection;


class MyCollection extends CustomCollection implements SearchResultInterface{

     /**
     * @var AggregationInterface
     */
    protected $aggregations;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param string $eventPrefix
     * @param string $eventObject
     * @param string $resourceModel
     * @param string $model
     * @param string|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,       
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->addFilterToMap('customer_name','firstname');
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    /**
     * @return AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve all ids for collection
     * Backward compatibility with EAV collection
     *
     * @param int $limit
     * @param int $offset
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {


        $custId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $this->addFieldToFilter('main_table.customer_id',$custId);
        $joinTable = $this->getTable('customer_entity');
        $this->getSelect()->join($joinTable.' as customer','main_table.customer_id = customer.entity_id',
                            array('customer_name'=>"CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname)"));

        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }       

}
```

This is my extended class

```
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'custom_id';

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }


    /**
     * Define model & resource model
    */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Company\Module\Model\Custom', 'Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom');
    }



}
```

I got the following error

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method 
>   Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Grid\MyCollection::getParam()
>   in
>   /var/www/html/mage2/mage212/app/code/Company/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Custom/Grid/MyCollection.php
>   on line 158

Comment: your get parameter code is correct !!! so post the error which you are getting .

Comment: I have tried this $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); $model = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http')‌​; print_r( $model->getParams());exit; But it gives empty array. i.prntscr.com/28d3caccfb4d465691362c4fb760f207.png

Comment: use data persister(\Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistor) to get URL param in controller using Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http, than use it in collection class, take guidance from this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139159/how-to-pass-data-to-uicomponent-area

Answer (score 53, accepted):

First, you need to inject  *`\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`* at **_construct** function then using

[Magento2 how to getRequest](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69540/magento2-how-to-getrequest)

`$this->request->getParam('id'`),you can your data

```
protected $request;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        ....//rest of parameters here
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
       ...//rest of constructor here
    }
    public function getIddata()
    {
    // use 
    $this->request->getParams(); // all params
        return $this->request->getParam('id');
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$model = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  

print_r( $model->getParams());exit;

But it gives empty array.
 http://i.prntscr.com/28d3caccfb4d465691362c4fb760f207.png

Comment: you have tried wrong once.. Please follow my once

Comment: @JancyAbraham When you inject the `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` in the construct method you receive current request (not new) with all parameters. When you use the `ObjectManager` you receive the new clear object without any params.

Comment: I have tried the construct method, Now I got this error 
`Missing required argument $model of Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Grid\MyCollection.`

Comment: @JancyAbraham If the `Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Grid\MyCollection` extends the `Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Collection` you should add the similar modifications in the `Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Grid\MyCollection::__construct` too.

Comment: @ Siarhey Uchukhlebau It is not working.

Comment: Thank You @ Siarhey Uchukhlebau  It works when changing the position of arguments in the construct function. No need to include this argument in parent construct.

Comment: I got param value. Now my collection is not filtered by this value. When I give static value,it works.

Comment: @JancyAbraham I am facing the same issue for filtering collection.

Comment: @AmitBera, this works if accessed in same domain, if accessed controller from other domain its showing blank

Answer (score 6):

You are trying in correct way.

```
 $custId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

You can try with below code also

```
 $params = $this->request->getParams();
 $custId = $params['id'];
```

Comment: Got error :

Notice: Undefined property: Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Grid\Collection::$request in /var/www/html/mage2/mage212/app/code/Company/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Custom/Grid/Collection.php on line 158

Comment: Can you show the \Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Custom\Collection  extended class name only ?

Comment: updated the code. please check

Comment: This is correct. Share the module if you can.