# How to pass data from UI Form to PHP Class

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, importexport, class, ui-form

I have created a form using UI component, This form has a select dropdown which displays option related to current entity id if form is in edit mode and all options if a new entity is being added by form.

UI Form

```
<fieldset name="EntityFields">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <!-- This field represents form id and is hidden -->
    <field name="question_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">                    
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">questionmanager_entity</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="question_type">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Ricky\QuestionManager\Model\UiForm\TypeList\Options</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Ricky_QuestionManager\js\form\element\options</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">question_type</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Question Type</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Question will use Field type on store front according to selected Question type.</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

I want to pass current question id to following class (* **if form is in edit mode**)

```
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Ricky\QuestionManager\Model\UiForm\TypeList\Options</item>
```

***Edit**
This is my option class

```
class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{

/**
 * Product collection
 *
 * @var \Ricky\QuestionManager\Model\ResourceModel\Question\Collection
 */
protected $collection;

/**
 * Construct
 *
 * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
}

/**
 * Get options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    foreach ($this->collection as $type) {
        $optionList[] = [
            'label' => $type->getTitle(),
            'value' => $type->getQuestionId(),
            'is_active' => $type->getIsDeleted()?false:true,
        ];
    }
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($optionList);exit;
    return $optionList;
}
}
```

Thankyou for you suggestion ans answer. :)

Comment: You can directly get the question id in your options class.

Comment: You need to just check the which action has called in your options class.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav, I have updated my question with option class. can you please explain me how can i get question id there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below options class which you have need to change.

```
class Options implements OptionSourceInterface 
{

/**
 * Http Request class
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
 */
protected $request;

/**
 * Product collection
 *
 * @var \Ricky\QuestionManager\Model\ResourceModel\Question\Collection
 */
protected $collection;

/**
 * Construct
 *
 * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * Get options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $questionId = $this->request->getParam('question_id', false);

    if($questionId) {
        //Your Code which you want
    } else {
        foreach ($this->collection as $type) {
            $optionList[] = [
                'label' => $type->getTitle(),
                'value' => $type->getQuestionId(),
                'is_active' => $type->getIsDeleted()?false:true,
            ];
        }
    }


    //echo "<pre>";print_r($optionList);exit;
    return $optionList;
}
}
```

Change as per id which you have passed in url and update code as per your need.

Thanks

Comment: Yes I already used this approach from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154134/magento-2-get-parameters-in-the-url ..... by the way thanks.

Comment: Welcom any time

Comment: Accept answer if it's useful.

Comment: You didn't really read the question, did you?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. The above suggestions will certainly work for retrieving parameters sent in the request, but does nothing for those of us who are looking to pass a parameter via the form XML (as the initial question asked and I was looking to replicate) when making a call to the Source's toOptionArray() method.

After a lot of "searching" for potential solutions, the answer presented itself once I dug into the original Magento class `Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\AbstractOptionsField::prepare()` method. Here we see that the `toOptionArray()` is called for the provided source class, with no parameters considered.

```php
public function prepare()
{
    $config = $this->getData('config');
    if (isset($this->options)) {
        if (!isset($config['options'])) {
            $config['options'] = [];
        }
        if ($this->options instanceof OptionSourceInterface) {
            $options = $this->options->toOptionArray();
        } else {
            $options = array_values($this->options);
        }
        if (empty($config['rawOptions'])) {
            $options = $this->convertOptionsValueToString($options);
        }
        foreach ($options as &$option) {
            //Options contain static or dynamic entity data that is not supposed to contain templates.
            $option = $this->sanitizer->sanitize($option);
        }

        $config['options'] = array_values(array_replace_recursive($config['options'], $options));
    }
    $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
    parent::prepare();
}
```

To accomplish the desired functionality, extending this method is the only real option in this context. So I added a rewrite entry to my di.xml:

```xml
<preference for="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select" />
```

and added this to my field "config" array:

```xml
<item name="options_params" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="parameter1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="parameter2" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

Then, in my custom `Select` class, I rewrote the `prepare()` method, adding support for passing any parameters through to the `toOptionArray()` as desired:

```php
// Accept parameters to pass thru toOptionArray()
...
$optionParams = [];
if (isset($config['options_params'])) {
    $optionParams = $config['options_params'];
}

if ($this->options instanceof OptionSourceInterface) {
    $options = $this->options->toOptionArray($optionParams);
} else {
    $options = array_values($this->options);
}
...
```

Works like a charm. Hope it helps you too.