# how i can get parameter value of url parameter in customer registration success observer magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-account, parameter

I have set link like this

```
http://localhost/magento/customer/account/create/?param_id=20
```

> how I can get that (param_id) value in **customer registration success** observer in Magento 2
>
> how I can do this??
>
> I already tried this answer but not working --> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/154141/73525
>
> Observer

```
namespace Lunatic\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class Setcustomer implements ObserverInterface
{

    const CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID = 2;
    protected $request;
    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
       \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {


        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        if ($customer->getGroupId() == 1) {
            $customer->setGroupId(self::CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID);
            $id=getIddata();
            $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);
        }

    }
    public function getIddata()
    {
        $this->request->getParams();

        return $this->request->getParam('id');
    }

}
```

> xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="setdealer_forcustomer" instance="Lunatic\Module\Observer\Setcustomer"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: please add your code here

Comment: added code......

Comment: You cant pass parameter in URL like this, Instead of this you can pass parameter into hidden field in get in your observer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your functuinn using $this

```
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {                
            $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
            if ($customer->getGroupId() == 1) {
                $customer->setGroupId(self::CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID);
                $id=$this->getIddata();
                $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);
            }

        }
        public function getIddata()
        {
           $this->request->getParams();

           return $this->request->getParam('param_id');
        }
```

Comment: this time going but in parameter array  doesn't have  any (paramter_id) in that array

Comment: What did you use in your url as`param_id` or `paramter_id` ?

Comment: http://localhost/magento/customer/account/create/?param_id=20

Comment: use `print_r($this->request->getParams());` to get your array of params

Comment: bro can i get your email id???

Comment: yah i used this but no index of parameter (this   parameter_id)

Comment: will check and let you know...

Comment: You cannot get params in observer you can get it only in controller i think so...try to use plugin method to achieve your solution

Comment: bro are in coimbatore...

Comment: Yes.....:-)..........

Comment: me  also   .....;) can i get your email bro

Comment: Check here to use plugins bro....https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html