# Magento 2 : Catalog Product save after Observer Event

Tags: magento2, product, admin, event-observer, catalog

I have a custom multiselect field in Products edit section.

[image]
The values in the multiselect values from my custom table. If I click on the save button in Manage Products section by selecting any one value. The changes need to be saved into my table. How can I do it with Observer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get product from save event observer - Magento 2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93975/get-product-from-save-event-observer-magento-2)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara, it's not a duplicate, but this can help to form a part of the correct answer

Comment: You can get all post data in your request. use http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/69541/2443 in your observer.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this [link for the event](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93975/get-product-from-save-event-observer-magento-2) `catalog_product_save_after` to save your value. You can get your value in observer file and initiate your model object and save value in your table or use direct SQL queries to save in your table.

Comment: I got the product in observer using $product = $observer->getProduct(); .But how can I get my custom field value.

Answer (score -1):

@V.P

If attribute is single then 
Try using  $product->getMycustomattribute();

if  attribute is single_value  then try
$product->getSingleValue();

Comment: In save after event you cannot set the value