# Multiple Controllers sharing same functionality

Tags: magento2, module

I have a module which needs multiple Controllers. Every Controller though starts with an authentification check provided by a GET Parameter. So instead of writing in every controller at the beginning the same code I am thinking of a better way. What is best practice here?
I thought of using a Helper, which works for sharing code but in the Helper I would need to call $this->_request->getParams(); which I don't know if this is possible.
Any hints or tips?

Comment: Thats possible. Go for it. You can use it in a helper.

Comment: But how do I get the request object into the Helper?

Comment: Try this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69540/magento2-how-to-getrequest

Comment: So do I set a constructor in my Helper/Data.php?

Comment: Yes. you can paste your code here so that we can check.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thank you @Kingshuk Deb