# how to get post data in Magento Model File - Magento 2x

Tags: magento2, model, post-data

I want to get **POST data in Model file**, Which is my custom file of `AccountManagement`

```
/app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Model/AccountManagement.php
```

> Note:

I can access it through `$_POST, 'superglobal'  variable` but i don't wanna use it that way, Because `it's not valid for Magento standard`.

Because **Magento** use to featch `POST` and `REQUEST` data using this method **in Controller**.

```
$this->postData = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
```

But i am not able to use same method in `Model` file.

So anyone have any idea to `fetch POST data in Model file IN Magento 2x, As per Magento Standard`

Comment: Inject `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below code. We will inject Http class in the constructor and use that to get post data. This is a standard way of Magento 2

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model;
class ModelClassName 
{
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function getPost()
    {
        return $this->request->getPost();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, let me try

Comment: is it worked for you ?

Comment: no, it's not working!

Comment: but when i used Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface  

it did worked. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69540/magento2-how-to-getrequest

Comment: I am not able to understand the reason, but thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for [reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69540/magento2-how-to-getrequest), it worked for me.

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost()
```

Or add `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` to the constructor parameters in your own classes:

```
<?php
namespace MyModuleNameSpace\MyModule\Block
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class MyClass
{
    /**
     * Request instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getMyPostParams()
    {
        $postData = $this->request->getPost();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getContent();
```