# Magento 2 rest api get params returns empty array

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Magento 2 rest api get params returns empty array can any one tell me where I am going wrong.

```
i/p: in postman body => raw => json
{
    "orderids":[1,2,3]
}
```

(or)

```
{
    "orderids":"1"

}
```

(or)

```
{
    "orderids":{
        "0":"1",
        "1":"1",
        "2":"1"
    }
}

<?php
namespace Test\OrderGridSync\Model;
use Test\OrderGridSync\Api\SyncInterface;

class Sync implements SyncInterface
{   

protected $_request;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
   $this->_request = $request;
}


/**
 * return order ids
 * @api
 * @param mix $orderids
 * @return mix 
 */
public function syncOrders() {
    print_r($this->_request->getParams());
    die('testing');
}
}
```

o/p:-

```
Array
(
)
testing
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass data in parameters in POSTMAN like this and try to get the params in mentioned function

```
http://<host>/rest/V1/<endpoint>?orderids=[1,2,3]
```