# How to create a product were the customer enters the price?

Tags: magento2, price, custom-options

New to Magento and I am trying to figure out how to create a miscellaneous product that initially has a price of zero.  I would like to have a field that the customer can enter any amount into and that become the new price of the product.  I have added a text field option but have no idea how to link it to update the price.  I have tried to create a event/observer but get lost in the process.  Any help or at least pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.  I am using magento 2.2.5

Comment: jamil, I have played around with the plugin, but I do have other products that are not user defined price. I will attempt to create my own product, which does seem like the best way to go. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and from the info your provided I believe that I should be able to manage. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

#### Plugin

You could look into using `before` `after` and `around` plugins and write a module to replace the price with `$_POST` information.

`Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price` has a method called `getPrice()` and various product types can extend this. If your product is a default type, write an `after` method that returns the user provided information, but you probably want to check the value first. If your catalog has other items which do not have user-defined prices, or you plan to in the future, then you will need to use custom logic to determine if `getPrice` is being called on the right item.

#### Custom Product Type

Depending on your situation I would take it a step further and instead of using a Plugin, consider making a custom product type. With this you can define a price model specifically for your custom product type. To do this you make a file `etc/product_types.xml` in your module that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="user_priced_product" label="Custom Product Type Label" modelInstance="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type">
        <priceModel instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Price" />
    </type>
</config>
```

You then need a basic Product Model

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product;

class Type extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType
{
    const TYPE_ID = 'user_priced_product';
    public function deleteTypeSpecificData(){
        // method is abstract so must be defined here
    }
}
```

Then `Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Price` would be a custom class with a `getPrice()` that only gets called on your product type.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product;

class Price extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price {
    public function getPrice($product) {
        // code to get user input and return price here 
    }
}
```

The only disadvantage I have come across with custom product types is that many modules that extend functionality for products will only work for Magento's default product types and this can be limiting. I feel the organizational benefit is worth it.

So there's some code to get you started and at least a basic idea. I don't have time to write an entire module, but with this, and some research of your own you should be on the right path. Below are some links I used to write this answer and some that can help you.

#### Resources to help

- [Plugins - Magento2 docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)
- [Making a Plugin - Webkul](https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-use-plugins/)
- [Getting POST/GET data - StackExchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69540/magento2-how-to-getrequest)
- [Product Type - Classy Llama](https://www.classyllama.com/blog/custom-product-types-magento-2)

Please note I am not affiliated with any of the above and haven't tested any of their code directly.